# A question on Fourier Series and the frequency of the sinusoids

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier-series

On studying about Fourier series, I encountered 2 doubts:

1. How is it that a non-periodic function has a Fourier series?
2. When expressing a periodic function as summation of sinusoids, why is the fundamental (minimum) frequency taken to be that of the periodic signal? Why cannot one of the sinusoids have a frequency less than the fundamental?

I mean, we think of representing the signal in terms of sinusoids with frequencies greater than and equal to the fundamental frequency, and of course, there is the DC part as well. But, why is there no sinusoid with frequency less than the fundamental as well?

Is there any mathematical logic for the second point?

Comment: Why do you think that non-periodic signals have a Fourier series?

Answer (score 1):

1. A function that is not periodic doesn't have a Fourier series. What you *can* do is take a finite length interval and construct a Fourier series which approximates the function in that interval (and continues it periodically outside that interval).
2. The sum of several sinusoids with one of the sinusoids having (fundamental) period $T$ can never have a period less than $T$, simply because that one sinusoid will destroy periodicity (with period $<T$) due to its larger period.

Comment: Regarding point 2, why will that sinusoid destroy periodicity? Even a DC part exists. A DC part has the same value at every value of t. It's period is 0 in that sense. Right?

Comment: @Curiosity: Well, a constant has the same value in every period, so it doesn't affect periodicity. This is different from a *periodic* function (like a sinusoid), which cannot satisfy $x(t)=x(t+T)$ unless $T$ is an integer multiple of its own period.

Comment: I understand. Still, from a mathematical standpoint, can it be proved that frequency of any of the sinusoids cannot be less than the fundamental frequency?

Comment: @Curiosity: Sure, just use the equation in my previous comment. By definition it cannot be satisfied by a sinusoid with period greater than $T$.

Comment: Matt, regarding #2, how are you defining the *"period $T$"* of *"one of the sinusoids"*?  on the surface, it doesn't seem true unless you define explicitly that the period $T$ of a periodic function must be the **smallest** real and positive value $T$, such that $x(t+T) = x(t) \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \quad.$  that's what it seems to me.  if you don't make that the explicit definition of the period, then i think that #2 is false.  E.g. for $x(t)=\cos(2\pi t)$, this function is periodic and **any** positive integer can be its period $T$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Usually, by *period* we mean "fundamental" period, i.e., the smallest constant $T$ for which $x(t)=x(t+T)$ is satisfied. I've edited my answer accordingly to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Answering question 2: Say you have a periodic signal with fundamental period $T_0$ and fundamental frequency $f_0=1/T_0$. You want to write it as the sum $$\sum_k a_k \cos(2\pi k f_1 t + \phi_k),$$ where $f_1 < f_0$.

The problem is that the sum has fundamental period $T_1 = 1/f_1$, which contradicts your assumption that the fundamental period was $T_0$.

Comment: Yes. But, why does the frequency of the original signal need to be the fundamental? Fourier series even has a DC part with same value for all t. In that sense, it's  period should be 0.

Comment: The period is given by first harmonic. DC provides an offset, it cannot change the periodicity. By the way, a constant signal has no fundamental period, but it has all possible periods. Since a period has to be positive, it's incorrect to say that the period of DC is zero.

Comment: Right. Got it now. But, can it be mathematically proved that the frequency of any of the sinusoids cannot be less than the fundamental frequency?

Comment: I thought that's what I had done in my answer :) All you need to do is prove that the sum has fundamental $f_1$, which can be seen directly.

Comment: I meany, why cannot be take the fundamental to be something like f/2? Just by dividing the phase in your expression by 2 as a whole?

Comment: Because then the sum will not converge to your original signal.

Comment: Yes, exactly. How do I verify that?

Comment: The original signal has fundamental period $T_0$. The sum has fundamental period $T_1$. $T_0 \neq T_1$, therefore the sum is not the original signal.

Comment: You're welcome -- I hope the discussion was useful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example of question one works thanks to irrational numbers:

$$ \sin(x) + \sin(\sqrt{2}\,x) $$

is non-periodic. Any integer multiple of an irrational number modulo 1 is, by the nature of irrational numbers, non-zero.